# How do I add a 'checked'/'unchecked' event handler to a checkbox in codebehind using Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Okay this one's pretty straightforward. I'm creating a checkbox in my Page.xaml.cs file, and assigning it some params. I need to link to events for checked and unchecked. What is the syntax for this?

Also, my current code looks like this:

```
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.IsChecked = true;
        System.Windows.Thickness t1 = new Thickness(425,10,0,0);
        cb.Margin = t1;
        cb.Content = "Checkbox1";
```

I tried adding my function to cb.Checked but it gives me the following error:
"The event 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

CheckHandler is defined separately

```
public void CheckHandler(Object obj, EventArgs e)
{
       // Random stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't show the syntax you were using that resulted in the error. Am I correct in assuming it was this:

`cb.Checked = CheckHandler;`?

Because you wire up an event handler in C# like this:

`cb.Checked += CheckHandler;`

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, and thanks for your answer. This works as expected now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
cb.Checked += CheckHandler;
```